# Full page background image with pattern overlay

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

I would like to display an background image (background.jpg) that covers the whole page, but alongside this image I would like a dotted overlay (dotted-pattern.jpg). I have attempted the following code which theoretically should work but it doesn't, background.jpg only shows the image in correct proportions.

Here is the code:

```
background-image: url(images/dotted-pattern.png), url(images/background.jpg);
background-position: top left, center center;
background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: auto, cover;
-moz-background-size: auto, cover;
-o-background-size: auto, cover;
background-size: auto, cover;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a background-position property that includes a background-attachment value where it says "center center fixed". This should just say "center center", and you need an additional property for background-attachment.

Comment: You are correct, I have rectified this issue, if anything its made the page even worse.. the background.jpg image now has moved up the page only displaying the bottom half of the image.

Comment: Ok I can see what the issue is, its because the first image doesnt have a attachment value set so I've put the default down (scroll) and all is working as it should :)